# getting initial value of local state in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have some local state in my react native component. I save some data here and want to clean all local state on navigation from here. In my constructor,I have

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     date: '',
     selectedTourType: 0,
     tourType: [],
     group: false,
     no_of_days: 5,
     scheduled: false,
     search_text: '',
     searchedRegion: '',
     budget: null,
     editing: null,
     path: [],
     makers: [],
     selected: false,
     pressedIndex: 0,
     users: [],
     selected_users: [],
     destination: null,
     mapModalVisible: false,
     milestoneModalVisible: false,
     predictions: [],
     searchedRegionPredictions: [],
     polygons: []
    };
  }
```

Before navigation I have to setState all these properties as in constructor. Instead of this, if I will make a clone of state `const cloneObj = Object.assign({}, this.state);` and using this object for setState  `this.setState({ cloneObj });`. But I am making one more reference in memory here and each time a reference will be created.
This is what I have understand please explain me what is a correct way.

Comment: So, if you are navigating to a new route, why do you want to reset the state? Your component will be un-mounted anyway. And on the next mount it gets the initial state from constructor.

Comment: Sir,  There is a submit button by clicking which I use navigation. But I have seen some times if it is clicked twice then submitted twice. I have a logic that if some of value is null then it will not be submitted.  That's why i want to submit.

Comment: So, you navigate to a different route when the button is clicked?

Comment: yes sir and I want to reset on very first navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.setState({ cloneObj });
```

This will try to find `cloneObj` in `state` and replace it, but that is not you wanted

For that you need to do is:

```
this.setState({ ...this.state , ...cloneObj });
```

This will overwrite all the state properties matched with cloneObj. Basically it will reset the state.

---

So you can do it like :

```
// inside constructor
this.initStateData = {
     date: '',
     selectedTourType: 0,
     tourType: [],
     group: false,
     no_of_days: 5,
     scheduled: false,
     search_text: '',
     searchedRegion: '',
     budget: null,
     editing: null,
     path: [],
     makers: [],
     selected: false,
     pressedIndex: 0,
     users: [],
     selected_users: [],
     destination: null,
     mapModalVisible: false,
     milestoneModalVisible: false,
     predictions: [],
     searchedRegionPredictions: [],
     polygons: []
    };
this.state = { ...this.initStateData };
```

Then on any event you can do it like

```
this.setState = { ...this.state , ...this.initStateData };
```

Comment: Nothing to worry about, as it all will be destroyed once the page is reload/destroyed. now a days browser are more mature :)